# Не работает рекурсия

Tags: python, рекурсия, список

Только начал разбираться с рекурсией - не всё в ней понимаю пока. Я вроде бы использовал рекурсию, но у меня нет базового условия, которое я не понимаю, откуда взять абсолютно. Сама по себе программа работает и выдает всё, что нужно, но нет рекурсии.

Суть программы в том, что существует список, в котором надо сложить элементы, которые идут через х - т.е. х здесь как шаг.
Если x = 0, то сумма равно нулю автоматически
Если х вне диапазона, то сумма также равно 0

```py
 def sum_elements(nums, x) -> int::
    if x not in range(-len(nums), len(nums)) or x == 0:
        return 0
    if x > 0:
        nums = nums[x - 1::x]
        return sum(nums)
    return sum_elements(nums[::-1], -x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sum_elements([], 0))  # x = 0 -> 0
    print(sum_elements([1, 5, 2, 5, 9, 5], 3))  # 2 + 5 = 7
    print(sum_elements([5, 6, 10, 20], -2))  # 10 + 5 = 15
    print(sum_elements([5, 6, 10, 20], -20))  # x = -20 -> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия — это когда функция вызывает саму себя с уменьшением задачи.
У вас же функция `sum_elements` вызывает себя только в случае отрицательного `х`.
А всю работу (без рекурсии) делают строки

```
    nums = nums[x - 1::x]
    return sum(nums)
```

То есть тут такие варианты:

Если ваша цель — решить задачу, то эту задачу можно решить без рекурсии (что лучше), и вы это уже сделали.

Если ваша цель — поупражняться в рекурсии, то не надо использовать срез с шагом, а надо вызывать рекурсивно функцию подсчета, при этом уменьшая строку,
например, так:

```
return nums[x-1] + sum_elements(nums(х:), x)
```

Вам еще надо подкорректировать остановку рекурсии. Что будет. если вызвана функция `sum_elements([1, 2], 2)`? Что она должна возвращать?